# formatting a balloon in google maps API

Tags: api, google-maps

I have the following page:
http://www.skimmydiscs.co.uk/find-your-nearest-service-centre/
that allows you to search for a garage - eg, put in Scarborough and you get a list, choose the first location, and the map redraws showing a couple of place markers. clicking the markers brings up a balloon. I cant work out how to set the size of the balloon that pops up to say 400 wide by minimum 300 tall.....
here is the code on that page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
   var kmlfile = "http://www.skimmydiscs.co.uk/SMD_Data.kml?"+(new Date()).valueOf();
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.75,-3.5),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

// Action the Event Listener, zoom in and put the kml layer in place
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport); 
//add the layer
   var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlfile,{preserveViewport: true});
   ctaLayer.setMap(map);

      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(10); 
      }

    });


    //setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
    //setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
    //setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I'm in need of guidance, - any help much appreciated.

thanks
andy

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the balloon-opening-routine is "built-in" to Google maps' KML layer functionality, so I suggest these two hacks:

1, hard) use [GeoXML3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) which allows individual KML element manipulation such as described here: http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/Usage

2, ugly) edit the text inside your SMD_Data.kml file, adding some line breaks `<br><br>` to artificially force the balloon to become larger, or a blank spacer image